# Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm using CSOM and azure functions to create site collection.My workflow is first using GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext to get admin clientcontext,after site being created.Get the site collections clientcontext and then set site property such as add user to group,site owner etc.
It works well when debug local,but sometimes got error below:

```
Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. \"AssociatedOwnerGroup\r\nRootWeb\r\nSite\r\nMicrosoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current\r\n\""
```

and my code like this:

```
public ClientContext GetAzureADOnlyClientContext(string SiteUrl, string appId, string tenant, X509Certificate2 certificate,bool isadmin)
        {
            ClientContext newClientContext;
            try
            {
                newClientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(SiteUrl, appId, tenant, certificate);
                if (!isadmin)
                {
                    Web web = newClientContext.Web;
                    newClientContext.Load(web, w => w.Url);
                }
                newClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                return newClientContext;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                newClientContext = null;
                if (_logHelper != null)
                {
                    _logHelper.writeLog("GetAzureADContextError:"+ex.Message, TraceLevel.Error, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

in main function

```
 while (ctxNew == null && count <= Constants.NEWSITE_TRYCOUNT)
                    {
                        logHelper.writeLog(string.Format("Site is being provisioned, waiting for {0} seconds ({1})", Constants.NEWSITE_SLEEP_SECONDS, count));
                        Thread.Sleep((int)Constants.NEWSITE_SLEEP_SECONDS * 2000);
                        //ctxNew = spHelper.GetClientContextByCredential(cred, true);
                        ctxNew = spHelper.GetAzureADOnlyClientContext(hostUrl, spAzureAppId, spTenant, certificate,false);

                        count++;
                    }

                    if (ctxNew == null)
                    {
                        logHelper.writeLog("New site collection could not be retrieved from " + hostUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logHelper.writeLog("New site collection is created.");
                        Thread.Sleep((int)Constants.NEWSITE_SLEEP_SECONDS * 1000);
                        processRequestHelper = new ProcessRequestHelper(admClientContext, ctxNew, tenant, siteCreationInfo, log);
                        processRequestHelper.UpdateSite();
                        logHelper.writeLog(hostUrl + " has been updated.");
                    }



public void UpdateSite()
        {
            _logHelper.writeLog("Updating " + _newClientContext.Url);

            string description = _siteProperties.Description;
            string[] siteOwners = _siteProperties.BusinessOwnerEmail.Split(';');
            string[] members = _siteProperties.MemberEmails.ToArray();

            _tenant.SetSiteAdmin(_newClientContext.Url, _siteProperties.TechnicalOwnerEmail, true);
            _adminClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            if (siteOwners.Length > 0)
            {
                AddGroupUser(_newClientContext.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup, siteOwners);
            }

            if (members.Length > 0)
            {
                AddGroupUser(_newClientContext.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup, members);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
            {
                _newClientContext.Site.RootWeb.Description = description;
                _newClientContext.Site.RootWeb.Update();
            }

            try
            {
                if (_newClientContext.HasPendingRequest)
                {
                    _newClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                _logHelper.writeLog("Site updated!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logHelper.writeLog("Update site error:"+ex.Message, TraceLevel.Error, ex);
                throw;
            }
        }

 private void AddGroupUser(Group grp, string[] usernameArr)
        {
            foreach (string username in usernameArr)
            {
                try
                {
                    _logHelper.writeLog("Add User " + username + " to group.");
                    User user = _newClientContext.Web.EnsureUser(username);
                    _newClientContext.Load(user);
                    grp.Users.AddUser(user);
                    _newClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logHelper.writeLog("Add User " + username + ": " + ex.Message, TraceLevel.Error, ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

It seems that sometimes the clientconetxt goes null in azure funtion

Comment: It seems that AssociatedOwnerGroup return null when I call context.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Users.AddUser(user);
                                context.ExecuteQuery();